what is `isGoodProvider` in Telegram android application
I'm working on a project involving the Telegram Bot API and encountered a reference to a boolean named `isGoodProvider`. Could anyone shed light on what this boolean signifies? Is it a standard feature of the API, or is it part of a custom implementation by the developer community? Any guidance or resources pointing me towards understanding this concept would be greatly appreciated.
this variable is in route TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/ContactsController.java
and the variable defined like this:
        public boolean isGoodProvider;

Any guidance or resources pointing me towards understanding this concept would be greatly appreciated.
